# Node.js version goes back to 0.4 form 0.6 on reboot (NVM)

Tags: node.js

I used nvm (node version manager) to upgrade node form v0.4 to v0.6.9
I used the following commands:

```
node -v  -> v0.4.x
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install v0.6.9
//wait a while
node -v  -> v0.6.9
```

The problem is that each time I reboot my mac, node -v prints out v0.4. So I have to redo the procedure. I also have to run `rm -rf .nvm` before **git clone**. Can you please tell me why that happens and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info I think you're missing is that nvm lets you manage multiple versions simultaneously.  It does this by playing magic with your environment and paths.

After a reboot, I suspect you need only run these lines:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use v0.6.9
```

That should cause you to re-enter the "magic" nvm environment which you previously installed v0.6.9 in.

Comment: I actually used to do that, but then I gave up when I saw that at the end of the installation I saw "Now using node v0.6.9", but I'll give it another try, maybe I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, wait I I just read your answer fully. Now I understand, I guess I can mark your question as a correct one. But I want to wait and see if others have anything to say.

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing is that nvm installs node into a directory that is not in the normal executable path(/usr/bin/), so it's path have have to be put in PATH environmental variable every time you open a console or terminal which is what `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` does. So you have to do it every time you open your console or terminal. Technically you can also use node from the path like this:

```
/home/alfred/.nvm/v0.6.7/bin/node -v
```

And if you want to set your path to node automatically you should just put that line into `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` files. And you will have your node after each terminal start up.

Comment: It would be easier to use `nvm alias default 0.6.9` to set a default node vesrsion

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to see what's currently running:

```
node -v ; which node ; echo $PATH ; npm root -g
```

Now, install the new version of node you want:

```
nvm install x.x.x
```

Now, set this new version as the default version:

```
nvm alias default x.x.x
```

This won't change anything in your current session,
so create new session and then try this again:

```
node -v ; which node ; echo $PATH ; npm root -g
```

It should now show that the new version you've installed is now being used.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is:

```
nvm alias default v8.4.0
```

(insert your version number of course)